# Generate workflow plan for all combinations of inputs in Drake?

Tags: r, rlang, drake-r-package

I'm trying to create a workflow plan that will run some function `my_function(x, y)` for all combination of inputs in `my_dataset` but am stuck as to how to to generate the commands for drake's workflow without using paste.

Consider:

```
library(drake)
library(dplyr)

A <- 'apple'
B <- 'banana'
C <- 'carrot'

my_function <- function(x, y)
    paste(x, y, sep='|IT WORKS|')

my_function(A, B)

combos <- combn(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 2) %>% 
    t() %>% 
    as_data_frame()

targets <- apply(combos, 1, paste, collapse = '_')

commands <- paste0('my_function(', apply(combos, 1, paste, collapse = ', '), ')') 

my_plan <- data_frame(target = targets, command = commands)
make(my_plan)
```

Output:

```
> my_plan
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  target command          
  <chr>  <chr>            
1 A_B    my_function(A, B)
2 A_C    my_function(A, C)
3 B_C    my_function(B, C)
```

The above code works, but I am using paste0 to generate the function call. I don't think this is optimal and it scales poorly. Is there a better way to generate these plans? This may be less of a drake question and more of an `rlang` question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: This answer shows how to compose expressions using `rlang` framework. However, `drake` expects commands as character strings, so the final expressions would need to be converted to strings.

We begin by capturing `A`, `B` and `C` as symbols using `quote`, then computing all possible pairwise combinations using the code you already have:

```
CB <- combn( list(quote(A), quote(B), quote(C)), 2 ) %>% 
    t() %>% as_data_frame()
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   V1       V2      
#   <list>   <list>  
# 1 <symbol> <symbol>
# 2 <symbol> <symbol>
# 3 <symbol> <symbol>
```

We can now use `purrr::map2` to jointly traverse the two columns in parallel and compose our expressions:

```
CMDs <- purrr::map2( CB$V1, CB$V2, ~rlang::expr( my_function((!!.x), (!!.y)) ) )
# [[1]]
# my_function(A, B)

# [[2]]
# my_function(A, C)

# [[3]]
# my_function(B, C)
```

As mentioned above, `drake` expects character strings, so we have to convert our expressions to those:

```
commands <- purrr::map_chr( CMDs, rlang::quo_name )
# [1] "my_function(A, B)" "my_function(A, C)" "my_function(B, C)"
```

The rest of your code should work as before.

Ultimately, it's up to you to decide whether expression arithmetic or string arithmetic is more efficient / readable for your application. One additional thing to mention is the `stringr` package, which might make string arithmetic more pleasant to do.

Comment: Update: in development `drake`, commands are [expressions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html) now. See https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/700 and https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/700. Also note the `<expr>` header in the plan at the top of https://ropenscilabs.github.io/drake-manual/plans.html.

Comment: `drake` still understands character strings, but each `drake_plan(...)$command` is always a list of [expressions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html) now. The switch to expressions is a more appropriate and R-focused way to handle commands. The change will officially roll out in the upcoming release of version 7.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

`drake` now has a `map_plan()` function that does this.

- Help file and examples: https://ropensci.github.io/drake/reference/map_plan.html
- Section in the manual: https://ropenscilabs.github.io/drake-manual/plans.html#map_plan
- A more practical example: https://ropenscilabs.github.io/drake-manual/gsp.html

### Original post

Sorry I am late to this thread. A couple months ago, I added a section to the manual on [custom metaprogramming](https://ropenscilabs.github.io/drake-manual/plans.html#custom-metaprogramming) in the manual to cover situations like the one you raised. In the example, there is one solution using `rlang`/tidyeval and an equivalent solution using `as.call()` to create function calls.

Now that I think of it, this use case is general enough that I think there should be a straightforward `map_plan()` function to build the plan for you. I will work on it.

By the way, the `command` column in your plan can be a list column of language objects rather than a character vector, but you need a character column to use [wildcard templating](https://ropenscilabs.github.io/drake-manual/plans.html#wildcard-templating).